# perform window operation on a column only if not null or else select another column

Tags: function, pyspark, window

I have a table similar to below,

```
dir   cont    data
abc   NULL     1
NULL  chrew    2
NULL  daniels  3
```

Now I have to perform a window operation where partition by dir column only if not null or else by cont column

Is there anyway to do this?

```
w = Window.partitionBy(col("dir")).orderBy(col("active_dt").desc()))

dir  cont  data  Rec_v
abc  NULL   1    1
NULL chrew  2    1
NULL chrew  2    1
```

Comment: Your both the columns is having null. Wht would be the condition for partitionby if it's just having a single null or not any?

Comment: try something like 
`w =Window.partitionBy(f.coalesce('dir','cont')).orderBy(f.desc("data"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("abc", None, 1,), (None, "chrew", 2), (None, "daniels", 3)], ['dir', 'cont', 'data'])
df = df.withColumn("group_col", F.when(F.isnull('dir'), F.col('cont')).otherwise(F.col('dir')))
df.show()

+----+-------+----+---------+
| dir|   cont|data|group_col|
+----+-------+----+---------+
| abc|   null|   1|      abc|
|null|  chrew|   2|    chrew|
|null|daniels|   3|  daniels|
+----+-------+----+---------+
```

Then use `partitionBy` on column `group_col`